# Upload image in update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in Laravel5 I can't update image in Edit, when I upload new file, this result null...
Below my code in controller, routes and edit view.

here my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $slider = Slider::findOrFail($id);
    //$input = $request->all();

    // uploads image
    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $imagename = 'dpgomma_' . time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $imagename);
        $input['image'] = $imagename;
    }
    $slider->save($request->all());
    return redirect('/admin/sliders')->with('message', 'Slider Modificata');
}
```

my routes:

```
Route::get('/admin/sliders/edit/{id}', 'SliderController@edit');
Route::put('/admin/sliders/update/{id}',['as' => 'sliders.update', 'uses' => 'SliderController@update']);
```

My view form:

```
{!! Form::model($slider, [
'method' => 'put',
'route' => ['sliders.update', $slider->id],
'files' => true
]) !!}

{!! Form::token() !!}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('image', 'image:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::file('image', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::submit('Update Task', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `'files' => true` option in your Form opening.

Also, you can use `$request->hasFile('image')` and `$request->file('image')` instead of the `Input` facade.

I suggest you to take a look at [this](http://tutsnare.com/upload-files-in-laravel/), there's no more reason not to work.

Comment: What package are you using for Forms?

Comment: "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev"

Comment: Whats not working exactly? Because in slider you just save `$request->all()`, does the image is in public or not?

Comment: my image should be stored in public/uploads/, but this not happen... 
in DB i've stored only the original image name... but not " $imagename = 'dpgomma_' . time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();".
It's weird...   the same code when I create a new record, run perfectly...

Comment: Well for the DB, you have to uncomment `$input = $request->all()` and put $input in $slider

Comment: done, but not work.   Sorry, I've done a mistake in my last comment, the image is uploaded into the folder, but in DB she stored with a different name, not as variable $imagename... it keep your original name...

Answer (score 1):

Your database is not updating image name because the image name contains in `input['image']` and you updating your database with `$request` service container. So, the original name of your image going through $request service container like

```
$request = [
    'other' => 'other',
    'image' => 'you_original_image_name',
    'more_other' => 'more_other'
]
```

To update the database with desire file name change this line

```
$input['image'] = $imagename;
```

To

```
$request['image'] = $imagename;
```